# Посчитать количество слов в строке, которые начинаются на "t"

Tags: c++

Стоит задача, написать программу, пользователь вводит строку, на выводе программа показывает сколько слов в строке начинается с буквы "t", не работает счетчик, ничего не выводит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где допустил ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c=0;
    char a[100] = {0};
    cout << "Vvedite stroky: ";
    cin.getline(a,100);
    if (a[100] == 't') {
     c++;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
            if ((a[i] = ' ') && (a[i + 1] == 't')) {
                c++;

            }

        }
        cout << c;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В отладчике уже смотрели?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов смотрел, показывает все нормально, либо я криво смотрел..

Comment: if (a[100] == 't') { - это вы что проверяете? И как вы эту проверку в отладчике умудрились пройти?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, упс, прошу прощения, криво было, оно же должно быть if (a[0] == 't') теперь осталось разобраться почему он считает все буквы t

Comment: И снова смотрите в отладчике

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас вся строка забивается пробелами.

```
if ((a[i] = ' ') && (a[i + 1] == 't')) {
```

Надо

```
if ((a[i] == ' ') && (a[i + 1] == 't')) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, что вы уже исправили огрех с `a[100]` и теперь у вас

```
if (a[0] == 't') {
    c++;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
```

И что происходит, если у вас первый символ - **не** `t`? ваша программа не делает в таком случае ничего.

Вы цикл-то вынесите из тела `if`...

О том, что в цикле вы портите строку, вместо чтоб сравнивать с пробелом, вам уже написали.

Ну и, конечно, лучше не выскакивайте за пределы строки :), хотя в вашем конкретном случае ничего страшного не происходит - просто бессмысленно смотреть *последний* символ в строке - понятно, что за ним `t` вы не встретите.

И еще три маленьких вопроса - вам нужны только слова именно с маленькой `t`? вам не мешает, что выводимое число сливается в одну строку с "Для продолжения..."? вы смотрите на предупреждения компилятора? уж о присваивании в условии `if` он должен был вас предупредить...